# Makers Night, Maker's Night or Makers' Night?

Tags: possessives

We're running an evening craft fair soon and the posters are being designed. It's called "Makers Night", as the multiple independent stallholders who make and sell the crafts are also known as "makers". There have been differing opinions on the appropriate placement of an apostrophe in the "Makers" part of "Makers Night", or whether one is needed at all. Please help! :)

Comment: I think all three forms (Makers Night, Maker's Night and Makers' Night) are viable titles, but I can't muster any solid grammatical argument to justify that. The comparable "Ladies Night" is commonly written without an apostrophe. But there's also nothing wrong with making it possessive using the apostrophe, and both **Maker's** and **Makers'** are allowed (singular vs. plural). I think aesthetics may play a bigger part than grammar in deciding how to form a poster in a case like this.

Comment: Makers Night would look catchier on a poster.  Like Boys Basketball or Girls Basketball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since you are referring to "makers" as a plural, I would avoid "Maker's Night" (singular possessive) at all costs.

A common example would be "Ladies' Night" or "Ladies Night," which is also seen written both ways. In that case, though, the ladies are the customers, whereas your makers are the stallholders. Similarly, "Children's Day" or "Seniors' Lunch" refer to the patrons of the event. On the other hand, "Pizza Night," "DJ Night," or "Amateur Hour" refer to what is being showcased at the event.

Grammatically, "Makers' Night" would mean *the night belonging to the makers*, which is acceptable, although it may also imply that you are inviting makers to come, rather than inviting other people to come see the makers.

"**Makers Night**" is also acceptable, indicating *the night on which we have makers*, and arguably less stuffy and more aesthetically simple. That would be my personal recommendation.

I would summarize it as: "X Night" indicates that we are offering X on this night, while "X's Night" indicates that we are inviting X to come on this night. In practice, however, you will see all kinds of different styles, and it really comes down to what you think looks best.

Comment: Thank you @geekahedron - that's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Did you mean perhaps to write *seniors'*, plural possessive?

Comment: @jonathanjo Right, missed that one through a few iterations of edits